# Getting relational users from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am attempting to determine if the current user is in a relationship with my event.

In other words, I have events that users can join. I store a PFRelation of User in the Event Table.

I have tried

```
self.event.users.query().getObjectInBackground(withId: currentUser.objectId!, block: { (object, error) in
    if let error = error {
        //The query returned an error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        //The object has been retrieved
        print(object)
    }
})
```

and

```
do {
    let user = try self.event.users.query().getObjectWithId(currentUser.objectId!)

    if user == nil {
        currentUser.saveInBackground { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
            eventsRelation.add(object)
        }

        usersRelation.add(currentUser)
        object.saveInBackground()


    }
} catch {
    print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
}
```

But these each return the user no matter what. Even if they are not in the relation.

It is as if they are running the query on the whole user table.

How can I run it on just my subset?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the relationship to query on.

[See here for more documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relational-data)

So the code would look like this:

```
let usersRelation = event.relation(forKey: "users")

let usersRelationQuery = usersRelation.query()

usersRelationQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: currentUser.objectId!)
usersRelationQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else if let objects = objects {
        // The find succeeded.
        print("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
        // Do something with the found objects
        for object in objects {
            print(object.objectId as Any)
        }
    }
})
```

Note that the `event` variable above is from the database.

If we did not include the `whereKey` portion, then it would just get the ones in that relationship.